# Forming recurrence relations

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

I have a question on forming recurrence relations and calculating the time complexity.

If we have a recurrence relation T(n)=2T(n/2) + c then it means that the constant amount of work c is divided into 2 parts T(n/2) + T(n/2) when drawing recursion tree.

Now consider recurrence relation of factorial which is T(n)=n*T(n-1) + c . If we follow the above method then we should divide the work c into n instances each of T(n-1) and then evaluate time complexity. However if calculate in this way then answer will O(n^n) because we will have O(n^n) recursive calls which is wrong.

So my question is why can't we use the same approach of dividing the elements into sub parts as in first case.

Comment: "it means that the constant amount of work `c` is divided into 2 parts T(n/2) + T(n/2)"   - that's not the right picture.   Think of it as "first visit the children recursively.   Then visit the current node and incur the work valued there."   So for `T(n)=n*T(n-1) + c`, we first do `n` bits of work of complexity `T(n-1)`, then we do 1 bit of work of complexity `c`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let a recurrence relation be `T(n) = a * T(n/b) + O(n)`.

This recurrence implies that there is a recursive function which:

- divides the original problem into `a` subproblems
- the size of each subproblem will be `n/b` if the current problem size is `n`
- when the subproblems are trivial (too easy to solve), no recursion is needed and they are solved directly (and this process will take O(n) time).

When we say that original problem is divided into `a` subproblems, we mean that there are `a` recursive calls in the function body.

So, for instance, if the function is:

```
int f(int n)
{
    if(n <= 1)
        return n;
    return f(n-1) + f(n-2);
}
```

we say that the problem (of size `n`) is divided into 2 subproblems, of sizes `n-1` and `n-2`. The recurrence relation would be `T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + c`. This is because there are 2 recursive calls, and with different arguments.

But, if the function is like:

```
int f(int n)
{
    if(n <= 2)
        return n;
    return n * f(n-1); 
}
```

we say that the problem (of size `n`) is divided into only 1 subproblem, which is of size `n-1`. This is because there is **only 1 recursive call**.

So, the recurrence relation would be `T(n) = T(n-1) + c`.

**If we multiply the `T(n-1)` with `n`, as would seem normal, we are conveying that there were `n` recursive calls made.**

Remember, our main motive for forming recurrence relations is to perform (asymptotic) complexity analysis of recursive functions. Even though it would seem like `n` cannot be discarded from the relation as it depends on the input size, it would not serve the same purpose as it does in the function itself.

But, if you are talking about the **value returned** by the function, it would be `f(n) = n * f(n-1)`. Here, we are multiplying with `n` because it is an actual value, that will be used in the computation.

Now, coming to the `c` in `T(n) = T(n-1) + c`; it merely suggests that when we are solving a problem of size `n`, we need to solve a smaller problem of size `n-1` and some other **constant** (constant time) work like comparison, multiplication and returning values are also performed.

We can never divide "constant amount of work `c`" into two parts `T(n/2)` and `T(n/2)`, even using recursive tree method. What we are, in fact, dividing, is the problem into two halves. The same "`c`" amount of work will be needed in each recursive call in each level of the recursive tree.

If there were a recurrence relation like `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + O(n)`, where the amount of work to be done depends on the input size, then the amount of work to be done at each level will be halved at the next level, just like you described.

But, if the recurrence relation were like `T(n) = T(n-1) + O(n)`, we would not be dividing the amount of work into two halves in the next recursion level. We would just be reducing the amount of work by one at each successive level (`n`-sized problem becomes `n-1` at next level).

To check how the amount of work will change with recursion, apply substitution method to your recurrence relation.

I hope I have answered your question.